# Excel VBA - Extract range is missing or illegal error on Range.AdvancedFilter

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to debug some old code (not written by me) and I'm getting the following run-time error (1004) on the first AdvancedFilter method in the code below.

> The extract range has a missing or illegal field name

```
Application.Goto Reference:="first_line"
'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Name = "data"

Application.Goto Reference:="heading"
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Name = "base"

Application.Goto Reference:="col_last"
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Name = "test_last"



Sheets("work").Visible = True
Application.Goto Reference:="base"



Range("base").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range( _
    "CsummaryA"), CopyToRange:=Range("SsummaryA"), Unique:=False

 ' error actually happens at this line, not the previous one as I stated previously
Application.Goto Reference:="base"
Range("base").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range( _
    "Csummary"), CopyToRange:=Range("Ssummary"), Unique:=True
```

Any ideas on what could be causing the error?

Comment: Does the range being copied have any null headers?

Comment: The headers in both ranges look fine, but thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the column headers in both CriteriaRange and CopyToRange are exactly same in terms of how they are spelled and there are no null headers as JNevill mentioned. The order of columns doesn't matter as long as they as spelled the same.

Comment: The two ranges (CsummaryA and SsummaryA) in the line that errors are not even remotely similar. What is really confusing is how the error doesn't happen on the other line with similar code.

Comment: Can you paste an image of headers for both the advanced filter statements. That would help in identifying the possible reason for error.